# Forward context in Android

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I am writing client REST application for Android. Because in my main Activity there is a lot of methods I decided to move rest operations to new class 'RestClient'.

Over there I need application **context** to execute: `Volley.newRequestQueue(CONTEXT HERE);` and to create **Toasts**.

What is the best way to do that? 
I believe that making `static Context context` in Activity and then access it inside class is not the best way.

Comment: If you're going to store any kind of context, use `getApplicationContext()`. Application is a singleton, so you won't leak anything.

Answer (score 0):

The safest way is to always pass the `Context` to any method that needs it, e.g.

```
public void showToast(final Context context, ...)
```

so you can call it from an Activity as follows

```
showToast(this, ...);
```